# Is "criterions" a valid plural for "criterion"?

Tags: grammatical-number, dictionaries, greek, variants, inflectional-morphology

Is *criterions* a valid plural for *criterion*?

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/criterion) says it is, but [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/criterion?q=criterion) does not confirm or reject it.

Comment: **NO!** The fact that many people use the plural *criteria* loosely when they're [only talking about a single criterion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterion) doesn't mean we can all play fast and loose with basic grammar.

Comment: Although I can understand the "vote to close" on the grounds of "general reference", I agree with @Henry this question raises an interesting issue. Arguably the main reason why *criterions* is so uncommon - despite superficially being the "natural" choice - isn't so much because we're all careful to "get it right". It's because we *usually* use the plural - as with *data*, probably many people don't even realise it *is* a plural (they think [it's] like **sheep** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This is not an issue of basic grammar, but of spelling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "data" plural in Latin, but in English it is singular, namely, a collective (non-countable) noun, which, as you noted, we use almost exclusively over "datum" which is nowadays a somewhat pretentious synonym for "data point". Insisting that "data" is an English plural countable noun is an instance of hyper-correctness.

Comment: @Hexagon Tiling (edit: just saw that you said "collective noun" which I guess means exactly that, but wanted to make it clear it is used as a plural) in computer science we use "data" as plural, always. "Data are available", like "the Police argued they were...".

Comment: @HexagonTiling Scientists and technologists routines employ *data* in the plural, for they construe it to be a count noun not a mass noun. Those averse to *datum* as a singular may use *data-point* for a singular form. Those who use *data* as a mass noun and hence singular sometimes use *data-sets* for a collective plural.

Comment: @Hexagon Tiling: I don't have a position on the "correctness" or otherwise re usage for *datum/data*. I'm just agreeing with Henry that the reason *criterions* isn't likely to become acceptable any time soon may be related to the fact that *criteria* (like *data*) is increasingly used loosely as a mass noun, not a "countable". So people are likely to be familiar with the Greek plural, even though it's not a "regular" inflection.

Comment: Not _exactly_ the same question, but: *There is only one / Criterion. / Folks inferia / Say "one criteria".*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you use a word like *criterion* anywhere you are on the safe side by using the Greek plural, *criteria*. People who understand the former will get the latter, and vice versa.

Moreover, *criterions* is really **not** [common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=criterions,%20criteria&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) according to google n-grams.

Comment: Indeed *criteria* appears to have been [more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=criterions%2Ccriteria%2Ccriterion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *criterion* since about 1950

Comment: @Henry: you mean 'criterions' vs 'criteria', right?

Comment: @Mitch: No.   I think I meant what I said.  Follow my link to check.

Comment: @Henry: yes, 'criteria' is the more common term than either, but the appropriate comparison would be with 'criterions'. Those two are the suggested plurals of 'criterion' and so '-ia' and '-ions' should be compared? What is the relevance of comparing the frequency of usage of the singular '-ion' with the plural '-ion' (as you say in your comment)?

Comment: A. It is interesting.  B. If the Greek based plural *criteria* is more common than the singular *criterion* and sometimes used in its place then the potential plural *criterions* will be uncommon, in the same way that the Latin based plural *data* being more common than *datum* suggests that *datums* is uncommon.

Comment: @Mitch: If you had looked at Vladtn's link in the answer, you'd see that *criterions* effectively "flatlines" against *criteria*. You'd also note that all forms of the word were relatively rare until a century ago, and only really started to take off after WW2. There really is no issue about what plural form is used. But as Henry says, it does seem to be going the same way as "data", in that increasingly we *only* use the plural.

Comment: No, not vice versa. There is one person of my acquaintance who uses "criterias" as the plural of "criteria", apparently believeing that because we use "criteria" all the time, it must be the singular form of the word.

Comment: The OED gives the plural 'criteria', but comments ‘less commonly -ons', with one supporting citation from 1788. Only those with a pioneering spirit might be advised to use it. 'Criterion' is a Greek word rather than a Latin one, but the possibility that it might one day go the way of 'agenda'/'agendas' cannot be excluded.

Comment: @BarrieEngland The OED also mentions that occasionally one finds the Latinized form *criterium* in place of  Greek *criterion*, and gives 3 citations. Certainly both lead equally to a *criteria* plural. However, that word has come to mean a certain sort of bicycle race. (As yet unattested by the OED, but found elsewhere.) There is a commonplace tendency among casual speakers — and even casual writers — of English to misconstrue *bacteria* as a singular, which same speakers may also stumble over *criteria* in the same fashion.

Comment: I seem to remember a make or model of car called "Criterion" (not to be confused with a Citroen); two or more of such cars would be Criterions.  But otherwise, to me at least, the plural of "criterion" is "criteria".  [If there was such a make/model of car, I can't find it on Wikipedia; it's likely I misremembered; but the principle remains valid.]

Answer (score 13):

Let me emphatically echo FumbleFingers' comment: **NO!**

> [**Get It Right!**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/criterion)
>
> The plural form of *criterion* is *criteria*:
>
> *Decisions on whether to close schools are based on three **criteria**: (a) financial saving; (b) condition of the buildings; (c) educational provision.*
>
> People often confuse the singular and plural forms of this word, so if
>   you need to use it in the singular be careful to use the correct form:
>
> *The only **criterion** for being accepted into the program is that you should have a bachelor’s degree in a relevant subject.*

Answer (score 9):

(I’ll add this somewhat meandering discussion as an answer to bring together in one place my various comments posted elsewhere.)

Let me add that the regularized *-ion > -ions* inflection in English for Greek 2<sup>nd</sup>-declension nouns instead of the Greek *-ion > *-ia* is comparatively rare.  The *OED* attests only four instances of this that I can discover:

1. *criterions* from a single 19<sup>th</sup> century citation
2. *ganglions* from several 18–19<sup>th</sup> century citations
3. *parhelions* from several 17–19<sup>th</sup> century citations
4. *stephanions* from a single 19<sup>th</sup> century citation

Then again, any such noun is pretty rare in English.  I think the only even moderately commonplace Greek -*ion* word apart from *criterion* is the medical term *ganglion*, and it too was historically on occasion given a regularized English plural, even though *ganglia* is now standard.

There are just not that many -*ion* nouns in English that come from Greek nouns. An [*OED* search](http://www.oed.com/search?case-insensitive=true&f_0=Headword&langClass=Greek&nearDistance=1&ordered=false&pos_0=noun&q_0=%2aion&scope=ENTRY) looking for English headwords ending in -ion and derived from Greek uncovers only 96 terms, and some of these do not count.  For example, although *ion* is indeed < Greek *ἰόν*, that was the neuter present participle of *ἰέναι*  to go.

If you relax the language of origin restriction, searching for -*ion* nouns in English headwords returns around 6900 terms, showing how uncommon the Greek ones actually are.

Most Greek -*ion* words occur in technical English, where retention of classical inflections is always higher than in the general populace, a well-documented phenomenon of ‘precisionist technicalese’, as it were. Only *criterion* alone is moderately commonplace outside technical circles, although a scant few other -*on* words do occur, like *phenomenon* in the previous sentence. The rest are all technical terms such as *anthemion,  aphelion, hapax legomenon, idolon, lepton, mitochondrion, noumenon, polyhedron,* and *taxon*.

In computational linguistics, all the popular stemmers and lemmatizers (with one still-unpublished exception) do a distressingly poor job on technical writing, because they are ignorant of the classical inflections specialists continue to use with technical terms.  The biomedical literature is particularly rich in Greek terms, and computer programs attempting natural language processing on these corpora must be specially trained to handle things like *stoma, stomata* if you expect to unify down to common lemmas.

The route by which these Greek words were introduced to English is not uniform. It may be directly from Greek; it may have first gone through Latin to get here; and it may have spent a time on holiday in France or even in Germany  before finally making its way to us.  For some words, such as *parhelion* for example, more that one route of origin applies.  This multi-sourcing has led to a plethora of alternate forms. Here’s one example from the *OED* of how confusing the historical record of forms can be:

- α. 15–16 parelii (plural), 16 parelios, 16 parelius, 16 parhelius, 17 parhelii (plural).
- β. 16 parahelii (plural), 16 parelias (plural, irreg.), 16 parelion, 16 parhelia's (plural, irreg.), 16 parrhelions (plural, irreg.), 16– parhelion, 16– parhelions (plural, now rare), 17 parelium, 17 parhelium, 17– parhelia (plural).
- γ. 16 parelies (plural).

As I mentioned in a comment to Barrie, the *OED* also attests a Latinized form of the singular *criterium* to go with the Greek *criterion*, with three citations one from each of the 17–19<sup>th</sup> centuries and starting with John Donne.  Both forms conveniently become *criteria* in the plural.

There is however another, much more recent sense of *criterium* in contemporary English.  The [crowd-sourced  Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criterium) gives this sense as

- (*bicycle racing*) A mass-start road-cycle race consisting of several laps around a closed circuit, the length of each lap or circuit ranging from about 1/2 mile to about 1 mile.

Apparently, the plural for this particular sense is always *criteriums*, as grating as that may be to some ears. [The crowd-sourced Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criterium) also gives the abbreviation *crit* for the circuit race, but I can find no history of the origin of this *criterium* for this sense.

Long-term stability of classical inflections in English plurals is dubious. Most eventually get regular forms in English, but this takes much longer if it is only a technical term used by specialists.  In words of common usage, there is often a reanalysis of the classical form to better match the native form.  On the other hand, technical literature is now more accessible than ever before, and this may interfere with regularization moreso than in previous centuries.

For example, *data* is often reanalysed to be a singular instead of a plural. This becomes a problem if it is to be used as a count noun instead of mass noun, since that would lead to the double-plural **datas*, which has caused the more regularly behaving *dataset* and *datapoint* to spring up to work around that particular problem. Since we now have workable alternatives to address the mass- vs count-noun problem, I begin to doubt *datum/data* will be around that much longer in even technical English. No harm done, of course.

Similarly, casual speakers and writers, especially in newspapers and nontechnical magazines, are often found using *bacteria* and *phenomena* in the singular. You need only [check the prevalence of ‘a bacteria’ or ‘this bacteria’ in uncurated, crowd-sourced Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aLists_of_common_misspellings/Grammar_and_Misc) to see how commonplace such errors are.

Finally, I should note that occasionally both forms persist, potentially with different nuance, such as a multidimensional array having several *indices* but a book having multiple *indexes*.  It wouldn’t surprise me if casual speakers wrote ‘a criteria’ just as they so often write ‘a phenomena’ or ‘a bacteria’, unaware of or unconcerned with the chalkboard-scraping effect this has on some of us.

However, it seems to me that anyone conscious enough of the root lemma in *-ion* will choose the classical inflection rather than selecting the courageously regular  *?criterions*, let alone the Latinized *?criteriums* (apart from the race).

Comment: Don't you mean “if you expect to unify down to common _lemmata_”? ;-)  (And there is of course at least one other fairly non-technical _-on_ word: _lexicon_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Gee, now look what my Cerberus-trolling pulled in! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Worse is that the “still unpublished exception” no longer meets those criteria, as it has been published. However, my aversion to self-promotion precludes replacing that with a link to the paper.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, crite*ria* and crite*rions* can both serve as plural to the singular criterion.
Here's the link..
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterions

Answer (score 1):

Is *criterions* a valid plural for *criterion*?  In a hundred years it might be, with the tendency towards anglicizing everything, but not now. If your native language is not English, then just take it from native speakers that *criterions* sounds to their ear as unpleasant as the proverbial fingernails on the blackboard.

"Criterions" does, however, sound like it might be a great name for a ball team...:)

Comment: @jwpat7: Thanks for the edits/corrections.