# How to refer to specified 'criteria', as singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Criteria” versus “criterion”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/criteria-versus-criterion)

Criteria is a word which defines collective recommendations for any entity.

I was drafting an email to my client where I wanted to say "are these criteria same which are defined in the previous email?" and it clicked.

Will it be:

Are these criteria same which IS defined?

or

Are these criteria same which ARE defined?

because to my understanding, I am referring to the word 'criteria' which *sounds* singular?

Also, how can I miss 'Criterion'? What would be correct usage?

PS: I have sent email which says "are these criteria same which ARE defined in the previous email".

I like to keep my grammar refined whilst communicating with someone. Please advice.

Comment: Where to start...  Try: "Are these *the* same criteria that were defined in the previous email." or "Are these criteria the same as those defined in the previous email."

Comment: It's always plural.  The singular is "criterion".  But there is more amiss in your sentence.  Refer to Jim's two excellent suggestions above.

Comment: Thanks @Jim I figured the workaround for this but, my question is about using the word 'are' or 'is'.. suppose, I am speaking in a flow where I cannot go back and correct?

Comment: @jwpat7 Not at all, mate. Not at all.

Comment: If you can't go back and correct you are stuck with what you wrote.  Did you notice that both my suggestions used 'Are'?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are actually trying to ask when you write "*Also, how can I miss 'Criterion'? What would be correct usage?*" When you correct the errors in the rest of the post, please be sure to make those questions more clear.

Comment: Besides [question #12357](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/criteria-versus-criterion) that has two answers that point out *criteria* is plural and *criterion* is singular (so *criteria* requires a plural verb form), see *[Is “criterions” a valid plural for “criterion”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58188/is-criterions-a-valid-plural-for-criterion)* and *[Number that should be used here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38109)* which have answers noting the same thing:  use “criteria … are” or “criterion … is”.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Criteria* is plural. *Criterion* is its singular. As [answers to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/criteria-versus-criterion) note, it is apparently becoming acceptable to use the word *criteria* as both the singular as well as the plural form. But, it is unlikely that anybody here is going to recommend that you do so.

You would ask,

> Are these criteria the same as those defined in the previous e-mail?

If you are asking about a singular criterion,

> Is this criterion the same as the one defined in the previous e-mail?

FYI, "*a word which defines collective recommendations for any entity*" is not the definition of [criterion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criterion).

Comment: The use of criteria as a singular is usually when the word is being used loosely, especially in connection with an unknown number of other criteria. Criteria can also be refered to in singular form when talking about the multiple criteria as a pool.

Comment: And the answer to the *criteria* question may be "Some are, and some are not."